# Precise & Word Choice

Tags: paraphrasing

Here is my 'before' sentence.

> I love to travel because it is always fascinated me to
>   acknowledge/realize/discern knowledge what I had not known before.

I would like to make it more precisely and choose the best one among "acknowledge/realize/discern.

Here is my revised version. I apply participial construction to make my sentence more short and clearly. And I choose 'realize'.

Can I receive your advice for my revised version?

revised version

> I love to travel, fascinating me to realize knowledge what I had not
>   known before.

Answer (score 1):

I love to travel, which fascinates me because I realize knowledge that I had not known before.

1. '...travel, fascinating me...' is a run-on sentence. A run-on sentence is where the parts before and after the comma can stand on its own. You want to connect it with a FANBOY (for, and, nor, but, or, yet), so the second clause becomes dependent on the first.
2. Instead of what, you should use that.
3. Instead of to, a word that you should use is since, or because. This is because travel doesn't fascinate you to the point where you learn new things. Travel CAUSES you to learn new things.